# Core Data - Linking Between Objects

Tags: core-data, attributes, entity-relationship

I am quite familiar with dealing with simple entity relationships, such as making a group that contains a collection of many items. However, I'm wondering how to achieve a particular relationship within my data structure.

Currently my data structure is made of entity Group and entity Item which has a one-to-many relationship from Group. The item exists only in a single group. However, it can also provide a link to another group as required.

So an analogy for the situation could be: Group = House, Item = Inhabitants. I live at a particular house, but I can also provide information about where to find other houses.

Another analogy could be: Group = Playlist, Item = Songs. I listen to the songs of the playlist, then when I get to a particular song I can (optionally) decide to switch to another playlist.

[image: Idealised Relationship]

Now I am pretty sure this is not the way to achieve this behaviour. I had the notion that it should be an attribute rather than a relationship, but I don't know if there is a way to link attributes unrelated NSManagedObjects (that I know of).

I'm thinking that it's not impossible, just that it requires a little more understanding of databases to achieve. Any advice, tutorials would be greatly appreciated!
EDIT: This is my second attempt at the data structure. Instead of it being a relationship, I've made a integer identifier on the group, and particular items can store this identifier as necessary in the form of an attribute.

[image: Second Version]

The otherGroupIdentifier would store a value equal to identifier on the Group entity. That way I can link through to it as explained previously. However, this certainly does not seem to be the cleanest way to implement Core Data. Maybe what I am looking for is not possible or too complex for a Core Data system?

Comment: Can you provide any other use case or explain the playlist use case in more detail? Isn't it just a many-to-many relationship you need? A playlist can have multiple songs and a song can be added to multiple playlist?

Comment: I've touched up the original question as well.

Comment: Sorry, pressed return key too early!

Perhaps the playlist analogy was a little weak... an Item only belongs in a single group, but in certain situations an item can be configured to point to another group. Here's another example - Group = Family, Item = members. A member can also know of other families as necessary, but only belongs to a single family genetically.

Another example - Group = Battalion, Item = Solider. Soldiers can only belong to a single battalion, but can be trained to know about other battalions.